# Change label names in ggplot for boolean variable for R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, label

I was wondering how to change the labels of the values of a variable in a ggplot. The variable is a boolean which has the values "TRUE" and "FALSE" and shows the values "0" and "1" in the legend. I wish to change this in some string value if possible. I have included some sample code of the overall structure but the labels in the legend remain "0" or "1".

```
date = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
bool = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
bool <- bool ==1
value = c(1,4,18,34,6,8,4,3,6,10)
df = data.frame(date,bool,value)

testplot <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y=value, color=bool)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlab("Date") + 
  ylab("Value") + 
  ggtitle("Test") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "green"), labels = c("Sttring1", "String2"))
  ggplotly(testplot)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: easiest way is usually to transform the variable before ploting, eg. `bool <- factor(bool==1, labels=c("String1", "String2")`

Comment: also, your code appears to work, at least `testplot`, maybe it's a plotly problem